# etherchannel loadbalacing logic question

Tags: cisco, switch, etherchannel

[image]

Questions: How does etherchannel will loadbalance traffic here when traffic coming from internet, L3 will hash IP src-dst but one that traffic pass to first L2 switch (distributed) how does that traffic will loadbalance on 2G link using `src-mac`? what src mac address it would use and shared traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the channel balancing on a switch is based on the source MAC address, and you have a single MAC address sending the traffic, then the traffic will always use the same channel member link.

Remember that a MAC address will not cross a layer-3 device. The layer-3 switch will create new frames for traffic coming from the ISP, and the source MAC address will be its own MAC address.

If you have multiple VLANs, the layer-3 switch *may* have a MAC address for each, or it may have the same MAC address for all your VLANs. You can use the `show interfaces` command to see how your Cisco layer-3 switch does it; just look at the SVIs' MAC addresses to see if they are the same.

Once the traffic gets to the first layer-2 switch, the traffic will be biased toward a single link on the channels to the other layer-2 switches, at least per VLAN, and possibly for all the traffic.